# Converting images to video keeping GOP 1 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a list of images, containing incremental integer values saved in png format starting from number 1, which need to be converted to a video with GOP 1 using `ffmpeg`. I have used the following command to convert the images to video and subsequently used `ffplay` to seek to a particular frame. The displayed frame doesn't match the frame being seek. Any help?

```
ffmpeg -i image%03d.png -c:v libx264 -g 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: @Gyan: Question edited to include reply to your comment.

Comment: That looks like a different issue. ffplay should seek and present from seek point even if  it is not a KF.  So  that can't be used to diagnose KF cadence.